# Download images from Github in python

Tags: python, http, web-scraping, download

I am creating a model of image processing using Google Colab. I have a few images uploaded in a repository, lets say it has the following URL: https://github.com/repo. Instead of having to upload the images manually one by one to Google Colab, I want to use the command wget in order to download them without exiting my notebook. My problem is that I have to download the raw images, because otherwise, I would download the web page that shows the image.

The raw images have the following URLs: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/repo/1.jpg?token=

The token varies from sessions and each image has a different token. Is there a way to download an image from a repo either not having to access the raw page or via any API?? (because I suppose the tokens are generated randomly so trying to guess them would not be right)

Comment: Why don’t you just create a (shallow) clone via Git to download everything at once? That would be a lot more efficient than iterating over some directory index and downloading every file at once. `git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/user/repo target-folder`

Comment: this question is about web scraping... it's not about any of the other tags I just removed.

Comment: @poke that would also work if the repo was private right?

Comment: @PabloOchoa Assuming that you have the permissions to access the repo, then yes, you can use the Git credentials to clone a private repo.

Answer (score 0):

If your repo is public, You can use this link:

```
https://github.com/{username}/{repository}/raw/{branch}/file.jpg
```

Comment: Is there something similar that could be done if the repo was private??

Comment: "private" repo? you want to stick your nose into repositories that nobody's supposed to stick their nose in?